# AAB output file name and path gradle variable

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to move my aab build process from my local machine to GitHub Actions following [this post](https://medium.com/@niraj_prajapati/automate-android-app-publishing-on-play-store-using-github-actions-554de7801c36#:%7E:text=Automate%20Android%20App%20Publishing%20on%20Play%20Store%20using,Deploy%20to%20Play%20Store.%20...%20More%20items...%20) and using [this GitHub action](https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release). In order to do so I need the [releaseDirectory](https://github.com/r0adkll/sign-android-release#releasedirectory). In my project, unlike the example, I have two modules in the same project, so I have been trying to determine how to get the path from the `./gradlew bundleRelease`

On my local machine when I run different items from the build menu, the artifacts are written to different directories:

[image]

- Build APK > app/mobile/build/outputs/apk/debug/mobile-debug.apk
- Build Bundle > app/mobile/build/outputs/bundles/debug/mobile-debug.aab
- Generate Signed Bundle > app/mobile/release/mobile-release.aab

Ideally I would like to have the path printed during the build process so I can see the path in the GitHub Actions output, but I cannot determine the right variables to print in the build.gradle:

```
println("buildDir (mobile)=${buildDir}")
```

seems to print:

```
app/mobile/build/
```

Is there a more complete variable for the path of an aab file? I can understand the first two might be generated, but why is the third result so different? Both modules go to the same directory under the first module's directory.